# Image Processing in iPhone

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4, image-processing, ipad

Actually I am adding Image Processing Feature in my iPhone Application It should do Brightness, Contrast, Sharpen, Exposure....

But i am not able to Find any article/Tutorial on the Internet. Will you please help me to find any tutorial or tell me how can i implement the iPhone View Based Application.

I have found 1 link http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/10094-adjust-image-brightness-contrast-fly.html its worked also for Brightness but its not working on iPad.

So Suggest something that i can start with my Image Processing Logic.

Thanks

Rick Jackson

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I personally like the approach in the GLImageProcessing project from Apple's sample code. [Check it out](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Hello Felz Since i have not worked on OpenGL so its hard to understand that code but i have found this article which explains about image processing but not in detail here is the link fiveminutes.eu/iphone-image-processing if any 1 points me to some algorithm for brightness, saturation, hur, sharpness and contrast then it will be very good.

Comment: Nice article!. The issue with the Quartz approach is that it is slow. OpenGL is indeed more complex, but faster. It will depend on the specifics of your app if OpenGl is worth the trouble. My only tip: resize the image to the screen size for preview. That will make the processing much more responsive. Happy Coding!

Comment: Felz thanks for your reply........... but no help from your side regarding image manipulation using Quartz Approach show me some way how can i accomplish my task

Answer (score 4):

There are a few libraries that support image processing in Quartz. There are even a few categories on UIImage to do some basic stuff.

The following are a few examples:

- https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters
- https://github.com/cmkilger/CKImageAdditions
- http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/

But as said before by @Felz those libraries are slow because they use the quartz codebase, which isn't that fast (for example: changing the saturation of an image with a resolution of 1024x1024 might take up to 4 to 8 seconds, depending on which device your using).

If your project is iOS 5 or higher then you should **definitely** consider using [CoreImage](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html)

Comment: I would second the recommendation of using CoreImage if you don't need to support iOS 4.x devices. However if you want to go ahead with the quartz approach i've Open sourced an abstract class for manipulating images on a background thread https://github.com/veritech/FRImageOperation

Comment: Since this is a pretty old post I'd like to add the following one: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage. This one processes images on the GPU so it's the fastest one of them all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) framework created by [Brad Larson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson). It includes awesome image filters and also easy to use.