# Image enhancement in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Image Processing in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673050/image-processing-in-iphone)

In my iPhone app, I want to include image enhancement facility.

In a view, a user can see the selected image and from there, with the help of a slider they can set (brightness,contrast,hue,sharpness,saturation etc).

I don't have any idea how to do this. I have googled it but could not find any good tutorial or source code.

Please help me if somebody has any idea.

**I tried to use [this](https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters)-But when i add the classes from folder Curve, i cannot build my project-It shows build failed without showing any issue**

Comment: follow this SO question this may be helpful to you:
[link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673050/image-processing-in-iphone

Comment: look here https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is [GLImageProcessing](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html). It uses openGL to do the Image Processing, but it is really fast.

If you want some code with Detailed Explanation then I found one Beautiful Link for you :

[It's like photoshop for the UIImage class!](https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters)

You can also use [CKImageAdditions](https://github.com/cmkilger/CKImageAdditions).

Try this : [GPUImage framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

Hope it will be helpful to you. Enjoy !!!

Comment: @bhavn Ihave used your secon link in my app,but while building it shows failed with out having any issue...Can you say why ??

Comment: Can you add the code where the app crashes ?

Comment: it doest crash,it shows build failed
It happened when I add the classes(folder curve) from that project

Comment: Are those classes properly added to your project (Means if it is showing red text or not) ?

Comment: No nothing like that,they are being properly added

Comment: I added one more link to the answer, you can use that.

Comment: At last your second link worked for me...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you read about [CoreImage Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html)?

The Core Image framework provides:

- Access to built-in image processing filters
- Feature detection capability
- **Support for automatic image enhancement**
- The ability to chain multiple filters together to create custom
  effects

Answer (score 0):

CoreImage Framework is a good option. Also GPUImage, which is hosted on github here: GPUImage https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

It contains a huge array of filters and processors.

Answer (score 0):

Use sample code from ios library reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLImageProcessing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009053

This is better to implement inside your application.